# Match only digit and dot (.) which may or may not repeat

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to test following strings in VBA.

```
Test String                               Expected Result
10                                        TRUE
10.23                                     TRUE
10.24.01                                  TRUE
10.24.02                                  TRUE
11.1                                      TRUE
AAA-78-102396-AA-A00-00811-0000-02.zip    FALSE
AAA-78-102396-AA-A00-00811-0000-02.pdf    FALSE
```

As you can see I am interested in either digit or a sequence having dot (.)

I tried using following expression.

`\b[0-9(|\.)]+\b`

But unfortunately it is picking the numbers separated by - in the last two strings. How to handle this? I am basic user of `RegExp` and I tried to search before asking but couldn't get anything close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You could try **`\b(^\d+)|(\d*?\.\d+?)\b`***

*Working Demo here  https://regex101.com/r/acUmrB/4*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: This answer isn't exactly what you desire. It matches `.8` too and uses tokens in improper places. @shrivallabha.redij

Comment: @revo I don't have .8 and it worked with my data so I marked it as answer.

Comment: For sure it worked for you but doesn't guarantee to work as expected. @shrivallabha.redij

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just in Excel. If first column is A, put following formula in B2:

```
=IF(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", ""), FALSE()), TRUE(), FALSE())
```

regards.

Comment: Thank you for the formula. Excel related tags were added by 0m3r and not me. I was interested in pure RegExp based approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an optional second part of decimals:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$
```

`^` and `$` anchors matches start and end of input string respectively. If you want to match inside of a larger text replace them with `\b`.